# Реализация кэша результатов запроса к mysql своими мозгами

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, кэширование

Тривиальный вопрос.

В базе данных инет-магазина хранится абсолютно все - страницы, пункты меню, имена контроллеров, товары, категории, связи и т.д.
В связи с тем, что база данных будет обновляться нечасто, создание модуля кэширования запросов - актуальная задача. Полистал "гугл", почитал форумы. Решил сделать нечто похожее на мемкэш:

1. Статические таблицы (меню, контроллеры) несомненно сразу же сериализуются и записываются в файл.
2. Все запросы от пользователя (например, поиск товара по фильтрами) кэшируются - а именно, результат SELECT (массив) сериализуется и записывается в файл с хешированной меткой самого запроса. Если такая метка уже существует, то запроса к БД не происходит, а данные извлекаются из файла, десериализуются в массив и выдаются браузеру.
3. При изменении какой-либо таблицы администратором, **скорее всего** файл кэша полностью уничтожается, а браузер, не найдя кэш-файла, получает данные из БД и "дает команду" серверу создать на их основе кэш-файл в обновленном виде.

Насколько разумно такое решение? Учту все замечания и советы.

Comment: 1. Почему хотите писать в файл, а не в тот же мемкешд? 2. Использование штатного кэша запроса MySQL по каким-то причинам не подходит? Не эффективно?

Comment: Наверное, у меня нет времени изучать мемкеш. Да и весь движок уже почти полностью написан...

Comment: Вы при использовании мемкешд медленный диск не дергаете - все операции в быстрой оперативной памяти, а при желании вообще выносите его на отдельный сервер. В любом случае попробуйте реализовать через обертку, чтобы в дальнейшем можно было достаточно просто сменить хранилище.

Comment: Кешировать стоит не данные из базы, а готовые к выдаче куски html. А сами запросы к базе надо оптимизировать так, что бы не было особой разницы поднимать из файла с диска данные или перезапросить у БД. Если и это не помогает, тогда мемкешед. С ним не дольше разбираться чем писать сохранение чего либо в файл

Comment: "готовые куски html" - это и есть закешированные статические страницы, а если пользователь ищет товары с помощью нескольких фильтров, то результатом будет массив и никак не html-код...

Comment: "готовые куски html"  Ой ли. Их кэшировать гораздо сложнее, т.к. для одного пользователя этот кусок один, а для второго - другой. А если закэшируются элементы управления админа и случайно будут выведены пользователю? Зачем этот геморой с html?

Напишите обертку кэша для мемкэша и кэшируйте запросы к базе в нем. в качестве ключа можно использовать либо сам запрос, либо для выборок по id `table_name|id`, например `orders|123` или же имя класса вместо имени таблицы, если конечно у Вас все на объектах

Comment: @naym, не будет сложностей прикрутить мемкэш к уже готовому движку?

Comment: @Deus Все зависит от кода движка. Ели в нем есть необходимый уровень абстракции, то можно управиться за 30-40 минут. Вам от него (мемкаша) нужно всего то `set` `get` `delete` да `connect` методы. Главное не забывайте удалять из него устаревшие объекты.

Comment: В БД есть абсолютно статические таблицы, например, таблица с фактическими размерами изображений для тех или иных блоков контента (это я подсмотрел в движке PrestaShop) и другие таблицы со статическими данными. Или это лишнее? Просто завернуть их в xml-файл или обычный массив?

Comment: @Deus все данные храните либо в БД, либо в более быстрых хранилищах. Если Вам важна скорость доступа, забудьте про хранение данных в файлах, используйте инструменты заточенные для быстрого доступа к данным. Файлы - крайне медленное хранилище, т.к. они живут на диске, а он крайне медленный. Тот же mysql хранит часть данных в оперативке, что повышает скорость работы.

Comment: @Deus почему вы считаете что кеширование "кусков html"  предполагает именно статику. Вы же сохраняете в кеше с ключем состоящим из всех параметров запроса. Какая разница сохранить данные выбранные из базы или с тем же ключем сохранить уже готовую html приготовленную из этих данных. в большинстве движков шаблонизаторы очень тормозные и готовят вывод пользователю дольше, чем данные достаются из базы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам MySQL достаточно умён чтобы кешировать результат запроса! Пока таблицы, участвующие в запросе не поменяются, пока выделенной оперативки хватает, повторный запрос будет отрабатывать мгновенно.

С мемкешем или другим шаред мемори вы добиваетесь ровно того же результата: скорость в обмен на память. Попробуйте для начала дать БД больше памяти, это самый простой способ кеширования!

Comment: Вы пишите, что myslq достаточно умен, но почему-то практически все движки используют тот или иной "шаред мемори". Интересно, как я могу дать БД больше памяти?

Comment: Ну во первых поставить больше RAM на сервер БД. Потом тюнить настройки
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache-configuration.html
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7344/optimizing-mysql-query-cache-size

Comment: Имеется в виду кэш запросов MySQL, под него можно выделить фиксированный объем памяти. Однако, эффективен ли он в ваших условиях нужно смотреть по статистике - может статься, что он зря потребляет ресурсы (количество вставок больше, чем количество извлечений, или равно - тоже плохо). Плюс он не кэширует параметризованные запросы, поэтом, да, часто прибегают к внешнему кэшу.

Comment: Когда изменения происходят часто, __любой__ кеш будет неэффективен. Но MySQL следит за актуальностью кеша сам, а в случае внешнего кеша это становится вашей заботой. Лишнее место для тормозов и косяков. Еще и "состояние гонки" можно словить.

Comment: @artoodetoo, я использую stmt не для того, чтобы пользоваться эффективностью подготовленных запросов, а для возможности автоматического экранирования "опасных" символов. Упрощенный пример: $Stmt->prepare ("INSERT INTO t VALUES('$id', '$name'); $stmt->execute(). Кэширует ли MySQL такие запросы (без символов "?" в sql?)

Comment: А вы в курсе, что по умолчанию PDO использует не настоящие серверные prepared statesment, а свою эмуляцию? То есть просто мимо нашей проблемы. :)